# Jquery function is starting on click but I need to stop it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I always wonder that onclick functions start to a javascript or jQuery, but How does it stop? Finally, I faced with a function in my learning progress. May you help me to find a solution?

I want to stop this function on another onclick:

```
function live_preview() {
        var icon = document.getElementById('LivePreIcon');

        if (icon.classList.contains('fa-eye-slash')) {
            icon.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
            icon.classList.add('fa-eye');
            $('#result').keyup(function () {
                $('#dialog').html($(this).val());
            });
            return;
        }
        if (icon.classList.contains('fa-eye')) {
            icon.classList.remove('fa-eye');
            icon.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
            // Stop the jquery function here
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is unclear what you are asking imho. Do you mean you want to unbind any event or what??? Or just fire it once? Or stop event propagation?

Comment: there is a button to start stop. On click the event is starting but another click event is not stopping. How I stop to run this event?

Comment: function for same button?

Comment: set a variable on click for play and check with variable if that variable showing true that means its playing and let it go inside for stop functioality else it will play

Comment: a return statement will 'stop'/complete the function

Answer (score 0):

```
var play=0;
function live_preview() {
            var icon = document.getElementById('LivePreIcon');
            var play;
            if(!play){
                    if (icon.classList.contains('fa-eye-slash')) {
                      icon.classList.remove('fa-eye-slash');
                      icon.classList.add('fa-eye');
                      $('#result').keyup(function () {
                          $('#dialog').html($(this).val());
                           play = 1;
                      });
                      return;
                    }
            }
            else{
                  if (icon.classList.contains('fa-eye')) {
                      icon.classList.remove('fa-eye');
                      icon.classList.add('fa-eye-slash');
                      play=0;
                      return false;
                      // Stop the jquery function here


                  }
           }
        }
```